# Applescript mystery: A scientific notation conversion subroutine

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a bit of a mystery on my hands. I found a subroutine (http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=27520) to convert a scientific number into a string of digits. However, it seems to delete the remaining digits, no matter what I try.

"1.23456789E+4" should become "12345.6789". Instead, it just returns "12345".

Try running the following code and you'll see what I mean. I call a dialog to disclose the result:

```
set xx to 1.23456789E+4
set yy to number_to_string(xx)
display dialog yy

on number_to_string(this_number)
    set this_number to this_number as string
    set deci to character 2 of (0.5 as text)
    set x to the offset of deci in this_number
    set z to the offset of "E" in this_number
    if this_number contains "E+" then
        set y to the offset of "+" in this_number
        set the decimal_adjust to characters (y - (length of this_number)) thru ¬
            -1 of this_number as string as number
        if x is not 0 then
            set the first_part to characters 1 thru (x - 1) of this_number as string
        else
            set the first_part to ""
        end if
        set the second_part to characters (x + 1) thru (z - 1) of this_number as string
        set the converted_number to the first_part
        repeat with i from 1 to the decimal_adjust
            try
                set the converted_number to ¬
                    the converted_number & character i of the second_part
            on error
                set the converted_number to the converted_number & "0"
            end try
        end repeat
        return the converted_number
    else
        if this_number contains "E-" then
            set y to the offset of "-" in this_number
            if x is not 0 then
                set the first_part to text 1 thru (x - 1) of this_number
            else
                set the first_part to ""
            end if
            set the second_part to text (x + 1) thru (z - 1) of this_number
            set the converted_number to the first_part & second_part
            set n to text (y + 1) thru -1 of this_number as number
            set zero to "0."

            if n > 1 then
                repeat (n - 1) times
                    set zero to zero & "0"
                end repeat
            end if
            set converted_number to zero & converted_number
        else
            set converted_number to this_number
        end if
    end if

    return converted_number
end number_to_string
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

As for **why your AppleScript code didn't work**:

**Your code only pays attention to the *exponent*, and not to the number of digits in the *mantissa*** (the fractional part of the number before the exponent).

Thus, with `1.23456789E+4` as the input, strictly *4* digits of the mantissa are extracted to form the result, irrespective of how many digits the mantissa has: `1` & the *first 4 digits* of `2345678`, which yields `12345`.

---

Getting this right in AppleScript is nontrivial, so  **I suggest using `do shell script` with a shell command using [`bc`, a POSIX arbitrary-precision calculation utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html)**, which will get you there much more quickly:

```applescript
set xx to "1.23456789E+4" # define as *string* to avoid rounding errors

# Perform transformation via handler defined below.
set yy to my toDecFraction(xx)

display alert yy

on toDecFraction(numStr)

    local maxDecPlaces

    # For *negative* exponents: set the maximum number of decimal places in the result.
    # For *positive* exponents: the number of decimal places in the result is 
    # automatically chosen to accommodate all digits.
    # In either case: the max. number of decimal places supported is 2,147,483,647.
    set maxDecPlaces to 32

    do shell script "{ printf 'scale=" & maxDecPlaces & ¬
        "; '; sed -E 's/[eE]\\+?/*10^/g' <<<" & quoted form of (numStr as text) & "; } | 
          bc | tr -d '\\n\\' | 
            sed -E -e '/\\./!b' -e 's/\\.0+$//;t' -e 's/0+$//; s/^(-?)(\\.)/\\10\\2/'"

end toDecFraction
```

- `printf 'scale=<n>;'`, when piped to `bc`, instructs it to use a precision of `<n>` decimal places in the case of a *negative* exponent; if the exponent is *positive*, `bc` automatically picks a precision that preserves all digits.

  - The upper limit for the number of decimal place is a hypothetical `2,147,483,647`(!) (`2^32/2-1`), but note that the higher a number you choose for `maxDecPlaces` (in case of a negative exponent) or the more decimal places your input has (in case of a positive exponent), the longer the conversion will take, though *in practice there is little difference in performance between a limit of, say, 32 vs. 200(!) decimal places*. Note that truncation, not rounding occurs if the limit is too low.
  - It *is* possible to calculate the *exact* number of decimal places needed to preserve all digits, but it requires non-trivial lexical analysis, so choosing a high-enough upper bound is a pragmatic compromise.
- `sed -E 's/[eE]\+?/*10^/g''` reformats scientific notation to a fully equivalent arithmetic expression that `bc` can evaluate; e.g.:

  - `1e2` -> `1*10^2`
  - `.3e+1` -> `.3*10^1`
  - `2.5e-2` -> `2.5*10^-2`
- Passing that expression to `bc` simply prints its result *as a decimal fraction* with as many decimal places as implied by the input (in case of a positive exponent), or as specified via variable `scale` (in case of a negative exponent)
- `tr -d '\n\'` is needed to remove `\` chars. and newlines that `bc` inserts when outputting numbers more than 70 characters long.
- `sed -E -e '/\\./!b' -e 's/\\.0+$//;t' -e 's/0+$//; s/^(-?)(\\.)/\\10\\2/'` cleans up the result removes trailing zeros from the result (and also removes the decimal point, if no decimal places are left), prepends `0`, if the (absolute value of) the result is < 1.

**Note**:

- **If the integer portion of the result is `0`, it *is* printed**, so, for instance, `1e-2` is printed as `0.01`, as is normal in AppleScript - not `.01`.

  - If you do NOT want the leading `0`, replace `-e 's/0+$//; s/^(-?)(\\.)/\\10\\2/'` in the code above with just `-e 's/0+$//'`.
- **`bc` is by design *not* locale-aware**, so the **radix character ("decimal point") it expects on input and produces on output is *always* `.`**

---

For comparison, here is a handler that uses **pure `bash` code to perform the transformation *lexically*** - as you can see, the effort of rolling one's own transformation is nontrivial - and would be much more verbose in AppleScript.

In practice, **the two approaches perform about the same.**
The advantage of this solution is that there's **no limit on the number of decimal places, and all digits are automatically preserved** and **unrecognized number strings reliably raise an error**.

```applescript
set xx to "1.23456789E+4" # define as *string* to avoid rounding errors

# Perform transformation via handler defined below.
set yy to my toDecFraction(xx)

display alert yy

# SYNOPSIS
#   toDecFraction(numString)
# DESCRIPTION
#   Textually reformats the specified number string from decimal exponential (scientific) notation
#   (e.g., 1.234e+2) to a decimal fraction (e.g., 123.4).
#   Leading and trailing whitespace is acceptable.
#   Input that is in integer form or already a decimal fraction is accepted, and echoed *unmodified*.
#   No fractional part is output if there is none; e.g., '1.2e1' results in '12'.
#   Numbers with an integer part of 0 are output with the leading zero (e.g. '0.1', not '.1')
#   Unrecognized number strings result in an error.
#   There is no limit on the number of decimal places and there are no rounding errors, given that
#   the transformation is purely *lexical*.
#   NOTE: This function is NOT locale-aware: a '.' must always be used as the radix character.
# EXAMPLES
#   my toDecFraction('1.234567e+2') # -> '123.4567'
#   my toDecFraction(toDecFraction '+1e-3') # -> '0.001'
#   my toDecFraction('-1.23e+3') # -> '-1230'
#   my toDecFraction ('1e-1') # -> '0.01'
on toDecFraction(numStr)
    try
        do shell script "
toDecFraction() {
  local numStr leadingZero sign intPart fractPart expSign exponent allDigits intDigitCount intDigits fractDigits padCount result
  { [[ $1 == '--' ]] && shift; } || { [[ $1 == '-z' ]] && { leadingZero=1; shift; } }
  read -r numStr <<<\"$1\" # trim leading and trailing whitespace
  # Parse into constituent parts and fail, if not recognized as decimal integer / exponential notation.
  [[ $numStr =~ ^([+-]?)([[:digit:]]+)?\\.?(([[:digit:]]+)?([eE]([+-]?)([[:digit:]]+))?)?$ ]] || return 1
  sign=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} intPart=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  fractPart=${BASH_REMATCH[4]} expSign=${BASH_REMATCH[6]} exponent=${BASH_REMATCH[7]}
  # If there's neither an integer nor a fractional part, fail.
  [[ -n $intPart || -n $fractPart ]] || return 1
  # debugging: echo \"[$sign][$intPart].[$fractPart]e[$expSign][$exponent]\"
  # If there's no exponent involved, output the number as is 
  # (It is either an integer or already a decimal fraction.)
  [[ -n $exponent ]] || { echo \"$1\"; return 0; }
  allDigits=${intPart}${fractPart}
  # Calculate the number of integer digits in the resulting decimal fraction,
  # after resolving the exponent.
  intDigitCount=$(( ${#intPart} + ${expSign}${exponent} ))
  # If the sign was an explicit +, set it to the empty string - we don't want to output it.
  [[ $sign == '+' ]] && sign=''
  if (( intDigitCount > 0 )); then # at least 1 integer digit
    intDigits=${allDigits:0:intDigitCount}
    padCount=$(( intDigitCount - ${#intDigits} ))
    (( padCount > 0 )) && intDigits=${intDigits}$(printf \"%${padCount}s\" | tr ' ' '0')
    fractDigits=${allDigits:intDigitCount} # determine what goes after the radix character
    result=${sign}${intDigits}${fractDigits:+.}${fractDigits}
    # Remove leading zeros, if any.
    [[ $result =~ ^0+([^0].*)?$ ]] && result=\"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\"
  else # result is < 1
    padCount=$(( -intDigitCount ))
    result=${sign}${leadingZero:+0}.$(printf \"%${padCount}s\" | tr ' ' '0')${intPart}${fractPart}
  fi
  # Trim an empty fractional part, and ensure that if
  # the result is empty, '0' is output.
  [[ $result =~ ^([^.]*)\\.0+$ ]] && result=\"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}\"
  printf '%s\\n' \"${result:-0}\"
}
toDecFraction -z " & quoted form of (numStr as text)
    on error number errNum
        error "Not recognized as a number: " & (numStr as text) number (500 + errNum)
    end try
end toDecFraction
```

---

Here's the **embedded `bash` function** with proper syntax highlighting:

```sh
toDecFraction() {
  local numStr leadingZero sign intPart fractPart expSign exponent allDigits intDigitCount intDigits fractDigits padCount result
  { [[ $1 == '--' ]] && shift; } || { [[ $1 == '-z' ]] && { leadingZero=1; shift; } }
  read -r numStr <<<"$1" # trim leading and trailing whitespace
  # Parse into constituent parts and fail, if not recognized as decimal integer / exponential notation.
  [[ $numStr =~ ^([+-]?)([[:digit:]]+)?\.?(([[:digit:]]+)?([eE]([+-]?)([[:digit:]]+))?)?$ ]] || return 1
  sign=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} intPart=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
  fractPart=${BASH_REMATCH[4]} expSign=${BASH_REMATCH[6]} exponent=${BASH_REMATCH[7]}
  # If there's neither an integer nor a fractional part, fail.
  [[ -n $intPart || -n $fractPart ]] || return 1
  # debugging: echo "[$sign][$intPart].[$fractPart]e[$expSign][$exponent]"
  # If there's no exponent involved, output the number as is 
  # (It is either an integer or already a decimal fraction.)
  [[ -n $exponent ]] || { echo "$1"; return 0; }
  allDigits=${intPart}${fractPart}
  # Calculate the number of integer digits in the resulting decimal fraction,
  # after resolving the exponent.
  intDigitCount=$(( ${#intPart} + ${expSign}${exponent} ))
  # If the sign was an explicit +, set it to the empty string - we don't want to output it.
  [[ $sign == '+' ]] && sign=''
  if (( intDigitCount > 0 )); then # at least 1 integer digit
    intDigits=${allDigits:0:intDigitCount}
    padCount=$(( intDigitCount - ${#intDigits} ))
    (( padCount > 0 )) && intDigits=${intDigits}$(printf "%${padCount}s" | tr ' ' '0')
    fractDigits=${allDigits:intDigitCount} # determine what goes after the radix character
    result=${sign}${intDigits}${fractDigits:+.}${fractDigits}
    # Remove leading zeros, if any.
    [[ $result =~ ^0+([^0].*)?$ ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  else # result is < 1
    padCount=$(( -intDigitCount ))
    result=${sign}${leadingZero:+0}.$(printf "%${padCount}s" | tr ' ' '0')${intPart}${fractPart}
  fi
  # Trim an empty fractional part, and ensure that if
  # the result is empty, '0' is output.
  [[ $result =~ ^([^.]*)\.0+$ ]] && result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${result:-0}"
}
```

---

Finally, here is an **even simpler shell command**, which, however, is **not recommended**, because it is **subject to the inherent rounding errors of double-precision floating-point values**, so **you cannot guarantee that all digits are (faithfully) preserved.**:

```applescript
set xx to "1.23456789E+4"

set yy to do shell script "awk -v n=" & quoted form of (xx as text) & " 'BEGIN \\
{ CONVFMT=\"%.11f\"; ns=\"\"(n + 0); if (ns ~ /\\./) gsub(\"0+$\",\"\",ns); print ns }'"

display alert yy
```

The command uses `awk`'s native ability to recognize scientific notation, and converts the resulting number back to a string using (implicitly applied) `printf` number format `"%.11f"` - i.e., 11 decimal places; any trailing zeros are trimmed (with `gsub()`) before the result is returned.

At first glance, this *appears* to be fine: the result is `12345.6789`.
**However, if you change the number of decimal places to *12* (`CONVFMT=\"%.12f\"`), a rounding error creeps in: `12345.678900000001`(!)**

You won't know in advance when this happens, so if faithful preservation of all digits is required, this approach is not viable.

Comment: I had a feeling a shell script would be necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @PatrickHennessey: You're welcome; there's also a simpler `awk`-based shell command, but it's subject to rounding errors.

Comment: Works well. The only comment I would add is that it doesn't add a leading "0" when the exponent is negative and end up with a number less than 1. I'm not sure if it's necessary but I normally do want it. I'm sure one simple line of code could fix that though.

Comment: @regulus6633: Yes, `bc` omits the `0` in that case; see my update for how to add it.

Comment: Well that was even less code than "one line" as I thought ;)

Comment: @PatrickHennessey: I've changed the code to return `0.1` instead of `.1`, for instance, because that's how AppleScript represents real numbers. I've also added a new function that wraps shell code that does its own lexical transformation, with automatic decimal-places handling and no limits. From what I can tell, it works well and performs about the same as the other solution, but as you can see, rolling one's own transformation is a nontrivial effort even in the usually much more concise bash code.

Comment: @regulus6633: I've switched the code to adding the leading `0` after all, because I've realized that that's how AppleScript itself represents decimal fractions < 1 in source code (and when converting to a string).

Answer (score -1):

A quick google search turned up [this](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-02.html), but as you pointed out it's the same base code that's not working for you. To make up for my silly mistake I wrote this applescript to do the job. It works with positive/negative exponents and positive/negative numbers. Good luck.

```
numberToString(-1.23456789E+4)

on numberToString(aNumber)
    set aNumber to aNumber as text

    -- check for a negative number
    set isNegative to false
    if character 1 of aNumber is "-" then
        set isNegative to true
        set aNumber to text 2 thru -1 of aNumber
    end if

    try
        set a to the offset of "." in aNumber
        set b to the offset of "E" in aNumber
        set c to the offset of "+" in aNumber
        set d to the offset of "-" in aNumber

        if b is 0 then -- we do not have an exponential number
            if isNegative then
                return "-" & aNumber
            else
                return aNumber
            end if
        end if

        if a is 0 then
            set firstPart to ""
        else
            set firstPart to text 1 thru (a - 1) of aNumber
        end if

        set secondPart to text (a + 1) thru (b - 1) of aNumber

        if c is 0 and d is 0 then -- assume a positive exponent
            set isPositiveExponent to true
            set thirdPart to text (b + 1) thru -1 of aNumber
        else if c is not 0 then
            set isPositiveExponent to true
            set thirdPart to text (b + 2) thru -1 of aNumber
        else
            set isPositiveExponent to false
            set thirdPart to text (b + 2) thru -1 of aNumber
        end if
        set thirdPart to thirdPart as number

        if isPositiveExponent then
            set newNumber to firstPart
            set theRemainder to secondPart
            repeat with i from 1 to thirdPart
                try
                    set newNumber to newNumber & character i of secondPart
                    if theRemainder is not "" then
                        if (count of theRemainder) is 1 then
                            set theRemainder to ""
                        else
                            set theRemainder to text 2 thru -1 of theRemainder
                        end if
                    end if
                on error
                    set newNumber to newNumber & "0"
                end try
            end repeat

            if theRemainder is not "" then
                set newNumber to newNumber & "." & theRemainder
            end if
        else


            set newNumber to ""
            set theRemainder to firstPart
            repeat with i from 1 to thirdPart
                try
                    set newNumber to character -i of firstPart & newNumber
                    if theRemainder is not "" then
                        if (count of theRemainder) is 1 then
                            set theRemainder to ""
                        else
                            set theRemainder to text 1 thru -2 of theRemainder
                        end if
                    end if
                on error
                    set newNumber to "0" & newNumber
                end try
            end repeat

            if theRemainder is not "" then
                set newNumber to theRemainder & "." & newNumber & secondPart
            else
                set newNumber to "0." & newNumber & secondPart
            end if
        end if
    on error
        if isNegative then
            return "-" & aNumber
        else
            return aNumber
        end if
    end try

    if isNegative then
        return "-" & newNumber
    else
        return newNumber
    end if
end numberToString
```

Comment: The OP's own code already contains the very code you've linked to - the only difference is that the OP's code extended the original code to also handle _negative_ exponents. Since the number that the OP uses to demonstrates the problem has a _positive_ exponent, the same problem exists in the code you link to.

Comment: Uh...did you read my comment? That's what I'm using already. My whole post is about how it doesn't work.

Comment: My mistake... I added an applescript to do the job. Good luck.

Comment: Almost there: you have leading-zeros problem with values such as `0.001e+3` (yields `0001`), but otherwise it seems to work well.